# Quotient of $C_0(X)$ by functions vanishing almost everywhere.

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, c-star-algebras

Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space and $\mu$ be a Radon probability measure on $X$. Let $C_0(X)$ be the space of continuous functions on $X$ vanishing at infinity and $N_\mu:=\{f\in C_0(X): \int_X |f|^2 d\mu=0\}$. Now I need to find a familiar space for the closure of $C_0(X)/N_\mu$ in the $L^2$ norm.

Edit: I am looking for the closure instead of the space itself.

I have a feeling that the answer would be $L^2(\mu)$, although I might be wrong. The reason being if we have a similar result like Lusin's theorem, we can approximate every measurable function supported on a finite measure by a compactly supported continuous function, and quotienting by $N_\mu$ only gives the equivalence relation in $L^2(\mu)$.

Note: This question appeared while trying to compute the GNS Hilbert space for an abelian $C^*$ algebras.

Comment: I think your guess is not correct.  Maybe you should try proving that $N_\mu$ is a closed ideal.

Comment: It very much depends on $\mu$. If $\mu(U) > 0$ for every nonempty open set $U$, then the quotient is (canonically isomorphic to) $C_0(X)$. If $\mu = \delta_a$ for some $a \in X$, then the quotient is just (canonically isomorphic to) $\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{R}$ (depending on whether you consider complex- or real-valued functions).

Comment: I edited the question, and am more interested in the closure.

Comment: @Ruy I have shown that $N_\mu$ is a closed ideal.

Comment: If by "closure" you mean "completion", then you indeed get $L^2(X,\mu)$.